# How do I embed a Twitter widget in Google site that filters by keyword?

Tags: twitter, widget, google-sites

I've added a Twitter feed into a Google Sites webpage using the technique here
http://sites.hanovernorwichschools.org/techsupport/howtos/google/embedding-a-twitter-feed-in-a-google-sites-page

The code for the widget is;

```
    <Module>
         <ModulePrefs title="Twitter" /> 
         <Content type="html">
         <![CDATA[ 
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/jobsnhs" data-widget-    id="524499648069640192" data-chrome="nofooter noborders transparent">Tweets</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)     [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>
        ]]> 
        </Content>
        </Module>
```

This works fine but now I'd like to filter the results. Currently the feed is showing job vacancies in the NHS and I'd like to refine it to only show tweets that include the word BRISTOL.
A search for `from:jobsnhs bristol` displays the correct results in Twitter but when I embed it into Google Sites it returns that No Tweets are found.

This is the code used;

```
    <Module> 
    <ModulePrefs title="Twitter"/>
    <Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Ajobsnhs+bristol" data-widget-id="524518920179302400">Tweets NHS jobs in Bristol</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);
js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
    ]]> 
    </Content>
    </Module>
```

I'm looking to filter by posts that include the word Bristol rather than the keyword #BRISTOL.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using that code, the easiest thing to do is to [use the official site](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#creating).

> To create a timeline you must be signed in to twitter.com and visit the [widgets section of your settings page](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets). From this page you can see a list of the timelines you’ve configured and create new timelines.

You can then create a query like `from:jobsnhs Bristol` and see all the tweets which match your criteria.

I note that @jobsnhs hasn't actually used the keyword "Bristol" yet - which may hamper your results :-)

Comment: The widget that the official Twitter site generates doesn't seem to display correctly on Google sites.
The code I posted was the code that Twitter generated, just enclosed in tags.

Also, when I search for posts containing the word Bristol I get a full page of results.

https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&q=from%3Ajobsnhs%20bristol

Comment: Those results are very old - they may not show up in the Twitter widget.

Comment: Those results are less than 2 months old.

Using the search above, the most recent post is from August 31st.